# Command to copy files from a repo to current one (React) on build/start

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have a repo with a React project. I need to, on `npm start` or `npm build`, copy all the files in another repo, and paste them into the folder `public/locales`.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are developing on some common flavor of GNU/Linux, and that the other repo is cloned on your local machine, change the `start` script on your package.json by this:

```
cp <route-to-the-other-repo-in-your-machine> public/locales && react-scripts start
```

And the `build` script on `package.json` by this:

```
cp <route-to-the-other-repo-in-your-machine> public/locales && react-scripts build
```

Comment: I'd need to `git pull` on the other repo, is there a way to do this from the command? to avoid having to switch to the other folder, pull, and then switch back to mine?

Comment: You could chain commands one after the other: `cd <route-where-the-other-repo-is-located> && git pull && cd <route-where-the-react-repo-is-located> && cp <route-where-the-other-repo-is-located> public/locales && react-scripts start`. A bit hacky though, I'd suggest checking if you have any other way less "breakable" way to achieve what you need.